# multiple classes in ActionScript package?

Tags: class, actionscript, package

I have read that you can only have one class by package in ActionScript. If you need helper classes, you have write this classes out of the package. Example:

```
package {
  public class A {}
}


class B {}
```

However, I found the following example in the adobe web site(:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9e.html):

```
package flash.xml 
{ 
  class XMLDocument {} 
  class XMLNode {} 
  class XMLSocket {} 
}
```

In the following Web page (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/packages.html), they said that you can only write one class of a package by a file:

```
// SampleCode.as file 
package samples{ 
  public class SampleCode {} 
} 

// CodeFormatter.as file 
package samples { 
   class CodeFormatter {}
}
```

Then my conclusion: you cannot write multiple classes of a package by file, right?. And this restriction is just to promote the good practices in AS3, right?

Sorry, if this question is too simple.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Of course you can have multiple classes in the same package

file  mypackage/MyClass1.as:

```
package mypackage {
    public class MyClass1{

    }
}
```

file mypackage/MyClass2.as:

```
package mypackage {
    public class MyClass2{

    }
}
```

But you can't have more than one public class per file (which should have the same name as the class).

You can have the helper classes outside the package block (in the same file), they are accessible only by other classes within that file:

file mypackage/MyClass3.as:

```
package mypackage {
    public class MyClass3{

    }
}

class HelperForClass3Only() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here might be some helpful information at http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/packages.html:

Most software projects contain many classes. Sometimes a project contains hundreds, if not thousands, of classes. Organizing those classes into related groups is standard practice and helpful. You use packages to organize your classes into related groups. The compiler also uses packages to define the full name for the classes they contain and to add a level of access control.